# Keep track of Touch Count on a <TextView>

Tags: android, android-widget

Thanx for taking the time to look at the question. I am trying out some android programming and I have hit a wall; not sure how to solve it. I am trying activate an animation for a specific  entity only when touch count is odd. That is `touchCount%2 != 0`.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

    ArrayList<TextView> textToDance = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    textToDance.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAD5));
    textToDance.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAD10));
    textToDance.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAD20));
    textToDance.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAD50));
    textToDance.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAD100));

    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            for(TextView txtAnimate: textToDance){

                if(event.getRawX()<= txtAnimate.getX()+txtAnimate.getMeasuredWidth() && event.getRawX()>=txtAnimate.getX()){
                    if(event.getRawY()<= txtAnimate.getY()+105+txtAnimate.getMeasuredHeight() && event.getRawY()>=txtAnimate.getY()+105){
                        helpAnimate(txtAnimate, 0);
                    }
                }

            }

        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d("MOVE","MOVE");
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("UP","UP");
        break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I tried to implement a HashMap but that map gets reset everything onTouch is called. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you want to initialize your array outside of the `onTouch` method.

```
ArrayList<TextView> textToDance = new ArrayList<TextView>();
textToDance.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAD5));
textToDance.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAD10));
textToDance.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAD20));
textToDance.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAD50));
textToDance.add((TextView)findViewById(R.id.CAD100));
```

Then you could create a map and initialize it with zero count values and register an onTouchListener (let's assume its your `Activity`)

```
HashMap<TextView,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<TextView,Integer>();
for (TextView tv : textToDance){
    tv.setOnTouchListener(this);
    myMap.put(tv,0);

}
```

Then in `onTouch` you would have something like...

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    switch (event.getAction()){
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          if (myMap.contains(v)){
              myMap.put(v, myMap.get(v) + 1;
          }
       break;
```

This probably isn't the most optimal way but it should be enough to get you started with achieving the kind of thing you're looking to do.

Comment: This works perfectly. I actually got rid of the ArrayList() and used a single HashMap altogether. Thank you